# sticky navbar allows overlappin of other div elements

Tags: html, css, css-position, display, sticky

Below I have the HTML AND SCSS(SASS) of a NAVBAR

```
<div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#main">Main</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bedroom">Bedroom</a></li>
                <li><a href="#living-room">Living Room</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bathroom">Bathroom</a></li>
                <li><a href="#kitchen">Kitchen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#others">Others</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

```
#navbar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 4rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $dark-color1;

    ul{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 3rem;
        background:$dark-color2;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;

    }
    li{
        display: flex;
        font-size: 1.3rem;     

    }

    a{
        color: $light-color1;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    a:hover{
        background-color: $light-color2;
        color: $dark-color2;
    }
}
```

As I add other div elements below it, for example the div of bedroom shown below{

```
<div id="bedroom" class = "room">
                <p class = "title"> Bedroom</p>
                <div class="flooring-tile">
                    <label for="Flooring-tile">Flooring Tile</label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </div>
                <div class="flooring-carpet">
                    <p class = "pname">Flooring Carpet</p>
                    <label for="Replacement">Replacement</label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <label for="Powerclean">Powerclean</label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
}
```

the Div below tend to overlap with the navbar. My goal is to create a page where there is no scrolling (overflow: hidden) and the user should navigate only through scroll bar.

But because the content of #bedroom is hiding behind the navbar, I can't allign the pages properly.

Comment: Can you please create a snippet of your working code

Answer (score 0):

I think `position: absolute;` can help with separating the contents for your navbar component. `Absolute` would suit the div component you used because it flows with the rest of the contents in a way. Check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).